"batch" removal of EXIF MPF data on Android phone before uploading to Google Photos
My Canon camera sets MPF in its EXIF data on and if there is a way to stop it, I can not find it.
This results in Google Photos saving the pictures in Original quality even though Storage Saver option is on - a known problem with Google Photos as discussed here.
At home I copy the camera pictures to my Linux PC and run a script to remove the MPF setting from a whole directory of photos in one shot. This allows the pictures to be backed up to Google Photos in Storage Saver as desired.
On travel, I back the camera photos up to my Pixel 6 phone using an OTG cable. I would like to have a way to remove the MPF setting similarly to what I do at home so that I could upload to Google Photos from my phone without blowing up my storage.
I have tried the app EXIF/XMP Tool and it does successfully remove the MPF setting. But in this app, I must open each photo one at at time and do the operation. If you take hundreds of pictures in a day, this is not workable. I seek a "batch" solution.
Is there a way on an Android phone to "batch modify" EXIF/MPF settings from many photos at once?

As you are familiar with Linux and scripting, you may want to try something similar on Android with Termux from github or F-Droid. You should be able to access the photos that are located in storage.
Be aware that there are issues with support on Android 12+ devices doing intensive computation on device.
